# Cant get window position in iFrame Phone Gap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

When using an iFrame in cordova and trying to get the window position it always returns 0 using:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/x3nnu35b Look below the vanilla code for a jQuery plugin that extends `.position` to include position for `$(window)` without nasty error code `(still requires vanilla code too tho)`